# How can I change this custom modifier to set input for its functions?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hello guys I found a solution for my answer ,It's a custom modifier for tapRecognizer :

```
struct TapRecognizerViewModifier: ViewModifier {

    @State private var singleTapIsTaped: Bool = Bool()

    var tapSensitivity: Double
    var singleTapAction: () -> Void
    var doubleTapAction: () -> Void

    init(tapSensitivity: Double, singleTapAction: @escaping () -> Void, doubleTapAction: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.tapSensitivity = tapSensitivity
        self.singleTapAction = singleTapAction
        self.doubleTapAction = doubleTapAction
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {

        return content
            .gesture(simultaneouslyGesture)
 
    }

    private var singleTapGesture: some Gesture { TapGesture(count: 1).onEnded{
        
        singleTapIsTaped = true
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + tapSensitivity) { if singleTapIsTaped { singleTapAction() } }

    } }
    
    private var doubleTapGesture: some Gesture { TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded{ singleTapIsTaped = false; doubleTapAction() } }

    private var simultaneouslyGesture: some Gesture { singleTapGesture.simultaneously(with: doubleTapGesture) }

}


extension View {

    func tapRecognizer(tapSensitivity: Double, singleTapAction: @escaping () -> Void, doubleTapAction: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {

        return self.modifier(TapRecognizerViewModifier(tapSensitivity: tapSensitivity, singleTapAction: singleTapAction, doubleTapAction: doubleTapAction))
  
    }

}
```

This is my code I want to pass a index in the ForEach and use custom logic in the singleTapAction function:

```
import SwiftUI

struct test: View {
    
    @State var devices : [Device] = [Device(name: "iphone"),Device(name: "ipad"),Device(name: "mac"),]
    
    func singleTapAction() {
        
        print("singleTapAction")
        
    }
    func doubleTapAction() {
        
        print("doubleTapAction")
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 15) {
                ForEach(devices.indices, id:\.self) { index in
                            
                            
                            Capsule()
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 42)
                                .overlay(
                                    Text(devices[index].name)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                )
                                .tapRecognizer(tapSensitivity: 0.2, singleTapAction: singleTapAction, doubleTapAction: doubleTapAction)
                                                  
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal,30)
            
        }
    }
}

struct test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        test()
    }
}

struct Device : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
}
```

If I write the code below :

```
singleTapAction(index : Int) {

}
```

it give me an error :

> Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> ()' to expected argument type
> '() -> Void'

Unfortunately I don't know how to change the code Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is not clear what `index` you are trying to pass. What do you want `index` to be?

Comment: I want to use it inside the forEach and pass the index in there the example above is not related to what I want its just an example how the tapRecognizer works.

Comment: Then how about you ask about `ForEach` instead, rather than this example that is "not related to what you want".

Comment: I added my code and this time I think explain better :)

Comment: So you want to access the `index` of the `ForEach` in `singleTapAction`?

Comment: Yes and doubleTapAction too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `index` of `ForEach` passed to `singleTapAction` and `doubleTapAction`, you shouldn't change the view modifier, because then the view modifier is responsible for passing the index to the closures, but the view modifier doesn't know about the `ForEach`, does it? The view modifier is not even applied to the `ForEach`.

Just change the method declarations:

```
func singleTapAction(index: Int) {
    
    print("single tapped index \(index)")
    
}
func doubleTapAction(index: Int) {
    
    print("double tapped index \(index)")
    
}
```

and then change how you call the view modifier. Instead of passing the methods themselves, pass a closure that calls the methods with the `index` of the `ForEach` as argument:

```
.tapRecognizer(
    tapSensitivity: 0.2, 
    singleTapAction: { singleTapAction(index: index) }, 
    doubleTapAction: { doubleTapAction(index: index) }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use:

```
func singleTapAction(index : Int) {
....
}
```

then you need to declare the same in "TapRecognizerViewModifier":

```
var singleTapAction: (index : Int) -> Void
```

and in init(...). Use it like this:

```
.tapRecognizer(tapSensitivity: 0.2, singleTapAction: singleTapAction(index: index), doubleTapAction: doubleTapAction)
```

Comment: No need to change the TapRecognizerViewModifier just use function inside { } solved the problem and I use your code its get a lot of error after changing the definition of singleTapAction